# ¿Cómo hacer un pipe para filtrar números enteros en Angular?

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, pipe

Es un placer saludarles, ¿alguien sabe como realizar un pipe para filtrar un string de numeros dentro de un arreglo de objeto?

Estoy tratando de filtrar dentro de arreglo de objetos una serie de números:

```
folderObjs = [
    {
      numero: '1234',
    },
    {
      numero: '8945',
    },
    {
      numero: '9897',
    },
    {
      numero: '1045',
    },
  ];
```

Pero, hasta el momento no lo he logrado, hice un pipe sencillo para poder filtrarlos:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (!value) return null;
    if (!args) return value;

    args = args.toString().toLowerCase();

    console.log(args);

    return value.filter(function (data) {
      return JSON.stringify(data).toLowerCase().includes(args);
    });
  }
}
```

Convierto el valor que recibo a string y luego se le aplica un toLowerCase para convertir el valor de la cadena buscada. Haciendo un console del valor que se busca, me di cuenta que por cada evento que se escribe dentro del input me retorno un `[object object]` Creo que tal vez no estoy haciendo correctamente la busqueda o tal vez es la conversión

```html
<form [formGroup]="smsForm">
  <div formArrayName="phones">
    <div *ngFor="let phone of phones.controls; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <label>Para:</label>
        <ngx-intl-tel-input class="flex-grow-1" cssClass="form-control phoneInput" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries" [enableAutoCountrySelect]="false" [enablePlaceholder]="true" [searchCountryFlag]="true" [searchCountryField]="searchCountryField" searchCountryPlaceholder="Buscar País"
          [selectFirstCountry]="false" [selectedCountryISO]="initialCountry" [separateDialCode]="true" [phoneValidation]="true" inputId="phoneInput" name="phone" [(ngModel)]="search" formControlName="phone" required>
        </ngx-intl-tel-input>
      </div>
      <button class="delete-btn" (click)="removePhone(i)">delete</button>
    </div>

    <div id="contenedor">
      <div>
        <button (click)="addPhone()">Agregar</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button (click)="onSubmit()">Enviar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-1" *ngFor="let data of folderObjs | filter: search">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ data.numero }}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

¿Cuál creen que sea mi problema? Tengo el proyecto en stack, por si gustan darle un vistazo: [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zhb7dh?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Podes usar el includes pero de esta forma `JSON.stringify(data.numero).toLowerCase().includes(args)` si pensaste en algo asi -->`function numero (data: numero[], numero: string):any{
return data.filter(obj=>obj.numero.includes(numero))
}
const juju=numero(folderObjs,'1045');
console.log(juju[0].numero)`

Comment: Si no soluciona tu problema con la respuesta que te dieron o con  la mia .podrias compartir tu codigo del componente? para ver como manejas el cambio en search quizás el problema si aun persiste es en referir a [(ngModel)]="search" en un formulario reactivo entiendo que a partir de la v6 ya fue declarado fuera de uso y lo adecuado seria ver los cambios mediante el formulario reactivo saludos

Comment: Hola! Lamento la demora en contestar, hasta hoy reabri el proyecto y no me funcionó. Me lanza "ERROR Error: args.filter is not a function" luego probe lo que me recomendaste y me lanzaba el mismo error. Aún tengo el proyecto público en Stack(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zhb7dh?file=src/app/app.component.html) quizás si sea el ngModel, pero cuando lo dejo con el formcontrolName no me lanza nada

Comment: lo miro me parece que puede estar el error también en el uso de FormArray

Comment: ¿Si? Aunque seguí la doc de Angular, además de que por el caso de uso lo realice de esa forma ¿qué me recomendarías hacer?

Comment: lo estoy probando ya te comento

Comment: Estaba pensando que en lugar de buscar por medio del valor del control buscar por medio del indice ¿qué opinas?

Comment: publico lo que pensé si no te sirve decime y lo elimino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Para visualizar el comportamiento agregar en app.cpmponent.ts y así tambien podrás ver la estructura generada
>
> ```js
> {{this.smsForm.value | json}}
> <h2>phones</h2>
> {{this.phones.value | json}}
> ```

Eliminar `[(ngModel)]="search"` causa de error para si darle valores de acuerdo a tu interes mediante smsForm  con codigo similar al siguiente:

```js
/ app,component.ts
import { AfterViewChecked, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CountryISO, PhoneNumberFormat, SearchCountryField } from 'ngx-intl-tel-input';
export interface numero {
  numero: string
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  smsForm : FormGroup;
  formArray = new FormArray([], [Validators.required]);
  folderObjs!: numero[];
  separateDialCode = true;
  SearchCountryField = SearchCountryField;
  CountryISO = CountryISO;
  PhoneNumberFormat = PhoneNumberFormat;
  title = 'angular-datatable';
  preferredCountries: CountryISO[] = [CountryISO.UnitedStates,
  CountryISO.UnitedKingdom];
  search!: any;
  formattedMessage!: string;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    ) {
    
    
    {
      this.smsForm = this.fb.group({
        
        phones: this.fb.array([]) ,
      });
      
    }
  }

  
  
  
  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log(this.formArray.status);
    this.folderObjs = [
      {
        numero: '1234',
      },
      {
        numero: '8945',
      },
     
    ];
    
    }
    
  
   
  onChanges(): void {
 // capturar cambios
  }
  newPhone(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      phone: '',
     
    })
 }
  addPhone() {
    this.phones.push(this.newPhone());
   
   
  }
  
  removePhone(i:number) {
    this.phones.removeAt(i);
  }
  onSubmit() {
  
const searchArry: numero[]=[];
    this.smsForm.value.phones.forEach((map:any) => {
      
      let w =map.phone.number;
       
searchArry.push(w)
  
      });
  this.search=searchArry[0];
  console.log('search!!!!!:',this.search,'searchArry[0]:',searchArry);
 ;

  }
  get formControls() { return this.smsForm.controls; }
    
  get phones(): FormArray {
        return this.smsForm.get('phones') as FormArray;
    }
}
 //appmodule.ts
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './components/users/users.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgxIntlTelInputModule } from 'ngx-intl-tel-input';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    FilterPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DataTablesModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    
    NgxIntlTelInputModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TooltipModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
// pipe.ts

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { numero } from './app.component';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
  
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  folderFilter!:numero[];
  
  transform(items: numero[], filtra: string): numero[] {
    if ( !filtra) {
      return items;
  }else {
   
    this.folderFilter=items.filter(item=>
      item.numero===filtra
      
   )
   
   if(this.folderFilter.length ===0){
    
    return items
  }
   else{
    
    return this.folderFilter
  }
   
   
    }
    
}

}

 <div class="wrapper">
<form [formGroup]="smsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div formArrayName="phones">
    <div *ngFor="let phone of phones.controls; let i = index">
      
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        {{i}}
    Phone number:
        <ngx-intl-tel-input [cssClass]="'custom'" 
        [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries"
        [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true" [enablePlaceholder]="true"
         [searchCountryFlag]="true"
        [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2,SearchCountryField.Name]" [selectFirstCountry]="false"
        [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.India"  [phoneValidation]="true"
        [separateDialCode]="separateDialCode" [numberFormat]="PhoneNumberFormat.National" name="phone"

        formControlName="phone">
        </ngx-intl-tel-input>
      
      </div>
      <button class="delete-btn" (click)="removePhone(i)">delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <p>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </p>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="wrapper">
<button (click)="addPhone()">Agregar</button>

{{smsForm.value | json}}
      <h3>Numero a buscar: {{search}}</h3>
<div class="card mb-1" *ngFor="let data of folderObjs | filter:search ">
  
    <div class="card-body">
  
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ data.numero }}</h5>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

El pipe:Maneja el caso en que no encuentra al numero mediante folderFilter asi la vista mostrara al listado completo pero cuando se ingrese a un numero y se hace submit si este numero esta en  folderObjs solo mostrara a ese numero si se ingresa un numero que no esta mostrara la lista original

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { numero } from './app.component';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
  
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  folderFilter!:numero[];
  
  transform(items: numero[], filtra: string): numero[] {
    if ( !filtra) {
      return items;
  }else {
   
    this.folderFilter=items.filter(item=>
      item.numero===filtra
      
   )
   
   if(this.folderFilter.length ===0){
    
    return items
  }
   else{
    
    return this.folderFilter
  }
   
   
    }
    
}

}
```

Comment: Hola! No habia retomado la pregunta, por algunas razones personales, pero volvi con el proyecto, estaba trabajando y comentarte que el filtro parece realizar la busqueda pero trae la data vacía, es decir la busca pero no la filtra. Una pregunta ¿porque agregó el filtro en el onsubmit? esa parte no me quedo muy clara ¡gracias siempre por su amabilidad!

Comment: fijate si el formato que usas en los numeros de folderObjs es correcto porque la librería que usas pide una cantidad de caracteres para que sea valido y agrega además agrega  caracteres por lo cual siempre te devolverá vacío si no tienen el formato correcto o si no lo consideras

Comment: Oh, es verdad, puede ser por eso que no lo busca, porque esa libreria ya tiene estipulado el formato. Voy a probar en este momento y te cuento. Voy a probarlo en el forma e.164, tal vez armando el objeto tal y como lo recibe la lib

Comment: edite la respuesta agregue varias cosas podes con eses código manejar por ejemplo mediante la suscripción a valueChanges el array agregado y con *ngIf la vista pero creo seria otra pregunta saludos

Answer (score 1):

En tu caso como es un arreglo de objetos debes filtrar según la propiedad, en este caso el numero, también realizar algunas correcciones a tu pipe podes verlo en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
 export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform( args: any[], value: any): any {
  if (!value) return args;
  if (!args) return [];



  return args.filter((data)=> data.numero === value);
}
```

}

Si necesitas una explicación mas amplia me comentas y te explico mas.

Comment: Haber si entiendo: Entonces debo filtrar el valor segùn lo buscado. Me encantaría que me explicarás más ampliamente porfis

Comment: Realice una modificación al comentario! para que lo veas! pero en respuesta a tu pregunta, debes filtrar el arreglo en base al valor buscado como lo ves aqui: return args.filter((data)=> data.numero === value), "data.numero" seria la propiedad.